# Setting up Account Balances in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to set up accounts in Access. The way the accounts work is after I put them in the system, they send us money and then that money is kept in their account until the end of the period.

So In access I have a table for the Companies and a table for Refills. I now want a query to calculate the amounts. I made a query and summed the totals and got what I wanted except the companies that are in the system but don't have money in the account won't show up.

What I want to happen is this

```
Company     Account Total
ABC         $100
DEF         $0
XYZ         $50
```

But what keeps happening is this

```
Company     Account Total
ABC         $100
XYZ         $50
```

How do I make the accounts with $0 balance show up?

EDIT:

So I figured out what is going on but still don't know how to fix it. I have 3 queries; Sum of all Refills, Sum of Purchases, and Current Balance (Rifills - Purchases). The companies that aren't showing up are the ones that haven't filed a refill. The Sum of Refills is not finding any refills so it doesn't show any values.

Hopefully I can get some help with this. Accounts seem easier in your head than in actuality.

Here are my Queries:

Refills

```
SELECT tblRefill.Company, Sum(tblRefill.[Refill Amount]) AS [Refill Amount]
FROM tblRefill
GROUP BY tblRefill.Company;
```

Purchases

```
SELECT [Order Summary].Company, Sum([Order Summary].[Order Total]) AS [Amount Spent]
FROM [Order Summary]
GROUP BY [Order Summary].Company;
```

Current Balance

```
SELECT [Refills].Company, [Refills].[Refill Amount], [Purchases].[Amount Spent], [Refill Amount]-[Amount Spent] AS [Current Balance]
FROM [Purchases] INNER JOIN [Refills] ON [Purchases].Company = [Refills].Company
GROUP BY [Refills].Company, [Refills].[Refill Amount], [Purchases].[Amount Spent], [Refill Amount]-[Amount Spent];
```

Comment: Go to SQL view and show me the SQL code for your query

Comment: Added. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the last query, try replacing "INNER JOIN" by "LEFT OUTER JOIN" or "RIGHT OUTER JOIN." Then run, hopefully you get results.